# Rails: scope filter question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have code like this:

```
query = Post.order("published_at desc")
query = query.where("location_id = ?", params[:location_id]) unless params[:location_id].blank?
query = query.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id]) unless params[:category_id].blank?
@posts = query.all
```

Basically a post has a location_id and a category_id. So now I am able to filter based on those. But a post also has_many tags.
For example, a post might have a java tag and a css tag.

I might want to filter all posts with just a java tag. Or posts with both java and css tag. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your Tag model, it's a little hard to provide a working example. However, here's an example assuming it is a has_many association where each tag belongs to a single Post, and the tag has a name field. You could define a scope in your Post model that filters based on a tag name:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_tags, lambda {|tags| joins(:tags).where("tags.name IN (?)", tags)}
end
```

Then use it like so:

```
tags = ["java"]
@posts.with_tags(tags)

tags = ["java", "css"]
@posts.with_tags(tags)
```

Comment: can you modify it so that I can use it with the code I have above?

Comment: It should work with your code, but I didn't test it. Is it giving you an error? Try replacing `query.all` with `query.with_tags([array of tags])` in your code.

Comment: undefined method for activerecord